# “La piscine n'était pas chauffée”: what isn't heated?

Tags: sens

The heating at the indoor swimming pool down the road frequently does not work. I would like to write this to a friend from France.

Is this correct ?

> La piscine n'était pas chauffée.

Or do I need to be explicit, that it was the water that was not heated?

> L'eau de la piscine n'était pas chauffée.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally, when you said "La piscine n'était pas chauffée", you talk about the building itself. You can eventually specify that you're talking about the water, but it's understandable when you said "La piscine n'était pas chauffée", that you're talking about the water

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: @Loic Il s'agit d'une métonymie. Lorsqu'on parle d'une piscine chauffée, on désigne implicitement le contenu (l'eau) comme étant chauffé.

Answer (score 1):

When hearing "*La piscine n'était pas chauffée*", I understand it to mean the pool water wasn't heated, not the building, but that shouldn't really make a difference anyway.

The reason why is indoor pools are themselves gigantic radiators so the building enclosing them rarely if ever requires any additional heating equipment.